# Able to insert data but unable to update

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm writing a Web app and using Excel as backend as i'm not supposed to use anyother. Here in my code i am performing a jdbc on 2 tables. Insert in 1 and Update in another. And below is my code.

```
public class PostDataDAO {
    DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();

    public void save(UserBean postBean) throws SQLException {
        String userName = new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName();
        System.out.println(userName);
        Connection conn, conn1 = dbConnection.conn;
        PreparedStatement ps, ps1 = dbConnection.ps;
        String excelPath = "D:\\Danny\\Result1.xls";
        String mainPath = dbConnection.excelPath;
        try {
            dbConnection.createClassForName();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=" + excelPath + "; READONLY=FALSE;");
            System.out.println("Connecting to database…");
            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }
            String insert = "insert into [result$] VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            System.out.println(postBean.getStartDate() + " from Bean" + " end date is " + postBean.getEndDate());
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
            ps.setString(1, postBean.getCaseNumber());
            ps.setString(2, postBean.getCaseOwner());
            ps.setString(3, postBean.getStatus());
            ps.setString(4, postBean.getIssue());
            ps.setString(5, postBean.getReason());
            ps.setString(6, postBean.getDateOpened());
            ps.setInt(7, postBean.getAge());
            ps.setString(8, postBean.getResolution());
            ps.setString(9, postBean.getFinalStatus());
            ps.setString(10, postBean.getStartDate());
            ps.setString(11, postBean.getEndDate());
            ps.setDouble(12, postBean.getTotalTimeTaken());
            System.out.println("Date from post bean ----------------- Case Number is " + postBean.getCaseNumber());

            System.out.println("Storing Object is Done!");
            ps.execute();

            conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=" + mainPath + "; READONLY=FALSE;");
            System.out.println("Connecting to database…");
            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");
            if (conn1 != null) {
                System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now! in the second block");
            } else {
            }
            System.out.println("for m second block " + postBean.getCaseNumber());
            String x = postBean.getCaseNumber();
            String updateSheet = "UPDATE [report1448039568905$] SET STATE = 1 where [Case Number] = '" + x + "'";
            ps1 = conn1.prepareStatement(updateSheet);
            System.out.println(" and " + updateSheet);
            ps1.execute();
            ps1.close();
            conn1.commit();
            conn1.close();
            ps.close();
            conn.commit();
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here my problem is, when i hit submit, the insert part is getting correctly posted. But the update part is a bit tricky and confusing. 
The System.out.println() is printing everything as expected, and to post the data I'm going to my code, delete a line, undo a delete, Save it. and i get the below message in my eclipse console.

```
Dec 01, 2015 7:18:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/SFDCTracker] has started
Dec 01, 2015 7:18:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/SFDCTracker] is completed
```

Once i get the above message, the other sheet is getting updated.

What i'm confused is, why am i doing this for the second table but not for the first. The first is getting inserted without any issues.

Please let me know how can i fix this.

Here when i did some research on this, i came to know that, I'm getting data from a excel sheet and i need to update the same Cell. Initially i thought that it might be a because it might be in read only, But i didn't get any exception.

And my second conclusion is that i need to rebuild. The data gets saved upon a new build. does this mean that that the excel file is released in mean while updating and when i hit run, it gets locked again? if so how can i fix this.

Thanks

Comment: how you tried copying all the data from this file and create new xls file and past it there? if not try this and then try to update

Comment: @Muhammad Ok, thanks for the tip, I'll check and update here. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. :-)